# Extra call in argument - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a trivia app and I am setting up all of the questions. I created a function to make questions quicker. But I run into an error which is 'Extra argument in call.'

```
func question(question:String, answerOne:String, answerTwo:String, answerThree:String, answerFour:String, correctAnswer:Int) -> NSArray {

    //Set the question
    var quizQuestion = question

    //set the answers and the right answer
    var firstAnswer = answerOne
    var secondAnswer = answerTwo
    var thirdAnswer = answerThree
    var fourthAnswer = answerFour
    var rightAnswer = correctAnswer

    //Add all the questions and answers to an array
    let questionAnswerArray = [question, firstAnswer, secondAnswer, thirdAnswer, fourthAnswer, rightAnswer]

    return questionAnswerArray
}


//This next line gives ERROR
var questionOne = question("What month of 1944 did D-Day occur?", "May", "June", "July", "August", 1)
```

When I try to call question, it gives me the option of NSArray or String. This seems simple but I have researched and found little. 
Any help is appreciated and please explain your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create an array of data like this. Instead use object orientation and create a Question class.

```
class Question
{
    var quizQuestion : String = ""
    var firstAnswer : String = ""
    var secondAnswer : String = ""
    var thirdAnswer : String = ""
    var fourthAnswer : String = ""
    var rightAnswer : Int = 0

    init(question:String, answerOne:String, answerTwo:String, answerThree:String, answerFour:String, correctAnswer:Int)
    {
        self.quizQuestion = question
        self.firstAnswer = answerOne
        self.secondAnswer = answerTwo
        self.thirdAnswer = answerThree
        self.fourthAnswer = answerFour
        self.rightAnswer = correctAnswer
    }
}

var questionOne = Question(question: "What month of 1944 did D-Day occur?",
    answerOne: "May", answerTwo: "June", answerThree: "July",
    answerFour: "August", correctAnswer: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the variable description in every argument after the first argument.

```
var questionOne = question("What month of 1944 did D-Day occur?", answerOne: "May", answerTwo: "June", answerThree: "July", answerFour: "August", correctAnswer: 1)
```